# Angular 2 : How to Prevent my data and html view by not reloading component on browser back navigation

Tags: typescript, angular, single-page-application, angular2-routing

I have two routes in my application
1) /home -- HomeComponent -- Home.html

```
    export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, CanReuse,OnReuse, OnActivate, OnDeactivate{
    ...
       constructor(private showHomeLogo:boolean;private showLogoutButton : boolean){
        console.log("Home page Constrcutor called");
       }
       ngOnit(){
         //after some service call for user authentication
         console.log("Home page ngOnInit called");
         this.showLogoutButton  = true;
         this.showHomeLogo = true;
       }
    routerCanReuse(nextInstruction: ComponentInstruction,
        prevInstruction: ComponentInstruction): boolean {
        console.log('routerCanReuse');
        return true;
      }
      routerOnReuse(nextInstruction: ComponentInstruction,
        prevInstruction: ComponentInstruction): void {
        console.log('route on reuse');
      }
      routerOnActivate(nextInstruction: ComponentInstruction, prevInstruction: ComponentInstruction): any {
        console.log("route activated");
      }
      routerOnDeActivate(nextInstruction: ComponentInstruction, prevInstruction: ComponentInstruction): any {
        console.log("route Deactivated");
      }
    }
```

2) /users -- UserComponent -- Users.html

```
    export class UserComponent{
    ...
       constructor(){
         console.log("Userpage Constrcutor called");
       }
       navToBack(){
        //navigation to back page
        window.history.back();
        //also tried the following
       //window.history.go("-1");
        //location.back(); //when I import Location from Angular/common
       //router.navigate(['home'])
      }
    }
```

When I click back button, I am able to come back to home page.
But the component is reloading it's constructor and ngOnit with which I am loosing the previous selections to show or hide some buttons on html.

I am using the Angular 2 rc1 router.

I need to go back to home page with the same state of the html previously where it was. i.e. not to reload the component.

Which means all my selections and entries of inputs should remain in the home page.

I suspect this is because of my HomeComponent is reloading on each navigation to this route which resulting my html page leads to initial state.

Please help.

Comment: You can use a service to maintain states between components. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: I mean state here the form data i.e. entered in home page is lost on navigating back to that page.
Yes I can use service to store that form entries and restore it when I come back to that page again.
But is there no way other than services?

Comment: There is no other way if you navigate away from a component. If you navigate from one route to another while both show the same component and only route parameters change `/somepath/:someparam` then you can use `CanReuse` to tell the router to not destroy and re-create the component. This should be default in the RC.3 router (seems not yet to work properly though)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, your correct. I have tested that "CanReuse". But it is not working properly. Need to wait for next release..

Answer (score 0):

you will need to remove your service function from your ngOnInit() and place them in a function outside it, because this will call your services every time which causes the loading.

then check if the contents need to be reloaded or not by checking if your values are empty or not.

simply dont let ngOnInit() always call your services.